# Dynamodb scan stops and results are returned with LastEvaluatedKey

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a http end point - when i hit the end point with my table name as query string parameter - i only get partial results with `LastEvaluatedKey`

```
import boto3
import json

print('Loading function')
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')


def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
        'body': err.message if err else json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    operations = {
        'DELETE': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.delete_item(**x),
        'GET': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.scan(**x),
        'POST': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.put_item(**x),
        'PUT': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.update_item(**x),
    }

    operation = event['httpMethod']
    if operation in operations:
        payload = event['queryStringParameters'] if operation == 'GET' else json.loads(event['body'])
        return respond(None, operations[operation](dynamo, payload))
    else:
        return respond(ValueError('Unsupported method "{}"'.format(operation)))
```

How do i make sure to scan all pages of the table.

Comment: I believe you have to use the `LastEvaluatedKey` in your next query to inform DynamoDB where to start rescanning from - there's a hard result limit you can hit.

Comment: how can i use the `LastEvaluatedKey` with in the same lambda function given above

Comment: You need to loop, checking if a `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response. If it is, there are more results so you requery supplying the `LastEvaluatedKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size
>   limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as
>   a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent
>   operation. The results also include the number of items exceeding the
>   limit. A scan can result in no table data meeting the filter criteria.

You need to requery, supplying the LastEvaluatedKey.

> **ExclusiveStartKey** The primary key of the first item that this
>   operation will evaluate. Use the value that was returned for
>   LastEvaluatedKey in the previous operation.
>
> The data type for ExclusiveStartKey must be String, Number or Binary.
>   No set data types are allowed.
>
> In a parallel scan, a Scan request that includes ExclusiveStartKey
>   must specify the same segment whose previous Scan returned the
>   corresponding value of LastEvaluatedKey.
>
> Type: String to AttributeValue object map
>
> Key Length Constraints: Maximum length of 65535.
>
> Required: No

A code example of the loop and check from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html#GettingStarted.Python.04.Scan:

```
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression=pe,
        FilterExpression=fe,
        ExpressionAttributeNames= ean,
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        )
```

Comment: I ma not sure about adding it to the same lambda code

Comment: @RUser This link shows you the syntax in Python: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html#GettingStarted.Python.04.Scan

Answer (score -1):

```
import boto3
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('master')

    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items'])

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        },
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }
```